# python string formatting need to quote format specifier, but string has quotes in it

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, pymongo-3.x

I am having issues trying to format a query string properly for Cassandra. I have this query that I am attmepting

```
session.execute("UPDATE query3 SET movietitle = '{:s}' WHERE itemid = {:d} and userid in (1, 2000)".format(cols[1], id))
```

The problem is that movietitle can be of the form `Toy Story (1995)` or `Mr. Holland's Opus (1995)`, so without the quotes, the parentheses would cause issues with the query. The single quotes, however, also cause issues because movie titles can have quotes in the name. Is there a neat way of structuring this query?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Python's built-in string `format` function to set values in the query string. This opens your application up to a whole class of bugs and security problems known as SQL/CQL injection attacks.

Instead, the DataStax Python driver supports parameterized queries.

[`Session.execute(...)`](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute) takes a `parameters` parameter, which lets you specify a *sequence* or *dict* of values to substitute.

For example, your query should look like this:

`session.execute("UPDATE query3 SET movietitle = %s WHERE itemid = %s and userid in (1, 2000)", parameters=(cols[1], id))`

Also look into using [prepared statements](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare) if you need to execute the same query multiple times. These have a performance benefit.